# how do i cast an integer to a character in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I am iterating over a list from 0-26, and would like to get the corresponding letter with each.  For example, 0 will give me letter 'A' and so on.

I know  that in java I can say:
    char A = (char)65;
and that will give me an 'A' from my 65 integer.

But how can i do this on the front-end with freemarker, I have no clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** In FreeMarker 2.3.22 you can just use the `(i + 1)?upper_abc` expression. (The `+ 1` is needed if `i` is 0-based.)

Unfortunately, FreeMarker has no operator for that, yet. Although it's still possible to achieve this purely in FreeMarker by building a string literal that uses a `\x` escape and then `?eval` it, that would be very ugly and inefficient. So the proper solution for now is to write your own `TemplateMethodModelEx`, and put it into `#import`-et utility library (if you have one) with `<#assign numToChar = 'com.example.NumToCharMethod'?new()>`, or add it as shared-variable in the `Configuration`.